# Can an ArrayAdapter used to fill a ListView be reused for a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout, android-arrayadapter

Happy Thanksgiving y'all!

So my Android app is using a custom ArrayAdapter class to populate a ListView page dynamically with a custom object class. Would it be possible to use this same ArrayAdapter to populate fields (TextView, ImageViews) on a LinearLayout page?

Basically, so my ListView page is: Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, etc...

And each Item 1, 2, 3, etc when clicked will have it's own individual page.

When I click on any Item #, I would want to use the ArrayAdapter to send the same info that shows on the ListView page for that item to show on the LinearLayout page. Is this possible? Or would I have to create another adapter for that individual page and pass in the same object holding the info?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am still a noobie at Android programming.

Also, if any of you have any tutorial pages you can point me in the right direction that would be very helpful! Thank you!

**Fragment Code**

```
public class DealsFragment extends Fragment {

@Override  
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show_deals, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.dealsListView);

    // Sample set of data passed to adapter for testing purposes
    Deal all_deal_data[] = new Deal[]
            {
                new Deal("Deal 1", R.drawable.test_image, 389, 700, 750, 500),
                new Deal("Deal 2", R.drawable.test_image, 20, 80, 1800, 1500),
                new Deal("Deal 3", R.drawable.test_image, 1932, 2000, 75, 60),
                new Deal("Deal 4", R.drawable.test_image, 198, 450, 450, 350),
                new Deal("Deal 5", R.drawable.test_image, 60, 70, 1500, 1100)
            };

    // Sets up adapter to pass data into XML
    DealAdapter adapter = new DealAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item_row, all_deal_data);

    // TO ADD HEADER ROW BACK IN
    // View header = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
    // LV.addHeaderView(header);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);       

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DealPage.class);  
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

That's how I usually organize my code.

Every activity has its own "show()" method, that is static (so you can call it without creating an Activity object):

```
public static void show(Context ctx, String string1, int int1, boolean boolean1){
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MyActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("arg_string1", string1);
    intent.putExtra("arg_int1", int1);
    intent.putExtra("arg_boolean1", boolean1);
    ctx.startActivity(intent);
}
```

From any other context (activity, fragment.getActivity(), service, ...) I call this show method to open the activity. For example from the ListView's onListItemClick listener (calling the listener this way works in a ListActivity or in a ListFragment):

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
      //Item with index = position has been clicked in listView
      MyActivity.show(this, item[position].name, item[position].number, item[position].mBoolean);
}
```

Then in MyActivity.onCreate() you call:

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("arg_string1");
int number = getIntent().getIntExtra("arg_int1");
boolean mBoolean = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("arg_boolean1");
```

Take a look at Bundle class, you can use it to pass data between activities and fragments.

Comment: Hi David. Sorry for the late reply! Been on vacation for the past week. I am actually having the ListView in a fragment page so the code you posted doesn't quite work with it. Can you point me in the right direction as to how to make it work in a Fragment page? Please note, the `Deal all_deal_data[]` will be coming from an external source, this was just for testing purposes. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also, how does the `show()` method work without creating an activity object? I am doing all the layout formatting of the page in an XML file for an Activity page. Can `show()` be used with XML formatting?

Comment: The only thing you should change is "this" when calling .show() in .onListItemClick(), change it to getActivity().
This is because show() requires a context and a Fragment is not a context, but the activity to which it's attached is a context (and you get it via getActivity()).

Comment: The .show is a static method, which means you can call it without creating the object. In a static method you cannot use variables from the object, but only static variables and the parameters you pass to the method.
.show() in this case just create the intent, fill it with your parameters, and start the activity with that intent.
Your activity will be launched and onCreate will be called. It works exactly the same as before, is just an utility to write less code (and do less errors with the parameters).

Comment: If you ended up using this method, remember to accept the answer! Bye!

Comment: I ended up going another route, but upticked your comment for all the help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i don't really get what u'r trying to say but from what i understood u need a list when clicked it goes to another page with title the text on item of the list clicked in that case u would want to create a listener on the list and on the click event u set a new intent where u put the name of the item clicked 
i would recommend for you to learn step by step frop this chain of video tutorials:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUOWNXGRc6g&list=PL023BC9408BAFEC0C

Comment: Thanks for the videos. I will check them out. That that's basically the gist of what I want. I already have a ListView that populates dynamically from an ArrayAdapter. And say each ListView row has Name, Image, etc... and when I click on a certain row, I want the Name, Image, etc for that row data to show up on a new activity. It's like a profile page for that individual row.

Comment: now i understaind what you want if u want something simple check the answer below or go to the videos so u create it yourself and understaind each bit of code written but if u want a customable example i will post to you an example of customable adapter in wich u can organise u'r list and control everything from design to clicks(on image text or any item u put in your list)